# Problem with formulating LP problem using binary variables

Tags: linear-programming

I have a problem with a task shown below.

I have I am supposed to use big M method, but I don't know how to estimate/compute the minimal value of it and how to implement it into the equations. Any help would be much appreciated:

> Use binary variables to algebraically express the set $Y$ defined as the set of all those $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in X$ that meet at least one of the following three constraints:
>   \begin{align}
> x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + 2x_4 &\leq 50,\\
> 3x_1 - x_2+x_4 &\leq 100,\\
> 3x_1-x_2+x_3 &\geq 20.
> \end{align}

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: 1) This may be more at home on [math.SE]. 2) Please transcribe the image using Markdown and MathJax formatting. 3) I have no idea what the "big M method" is supposed to be.

Comment: @Raphael 3) [big M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method)